# how to dynamically change video using jquery where the source path is stored in database and file in file system

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

i stored video file in file system and path in database.i'm able to display video using js and also jquery.i want to dynamically change the video when onclick on the list.but only first video is playing.here is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function fn() {
  var player = document.getElementById("videoclip");
  var mp4Vid = document.getElementById("mp4video");
    var a = '/site_media/media/';
  var b = document.getElementById("btn").value;
  var c = a + b;
  player.pause();
  document.getElementById("mp4video").src = c;
   player.load();
   player.play();
}
 </script>
```

```html
<body>
  <div align="right">
  <table border='1'>
  <tr><th>slno</th> <td>Filename</td></tr>
  {% for i in total %}//total contains the video paths(python)
  <tr>
  <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
  <td align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="fn()" id="btn" value="{{ i.vid }}"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
  </div>

<div align="center">
<video id="videoclip" width="320" height="240" controls='controls' autoplay>
 <source id= "mp4video" src="/site_media/media/upload/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video> <br></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

id's must be unique change html something like this:-

```
<input type="button" onclick="fn(this)" id="{{ i.vid }}" value="{{ i.vid }}"/>
```

and then in jquery code:-

```
function fn(dv) {
  var player = document.getElementById("videoclip");
  var mp4Vid = document.getElementById("mp4video");
  var a = '/site_media/media/';
  var b = $(dv).attr('id');
  var c = a + b;
  player.pause();
  document.getElementById("mp4video").src = c;
  player.load();
  player.play();
}
```